# Set Angular checkbox repeat from outside controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to simplify my controller. So I tried to set variable to populate my checkbox list from outside controller. Is it possible?

Here is my current code http://jsfiddle.net/ilmansg/Lx37kr3e/1/

VIEW HTML

```
<div ng-controller="AdminEventsCtrl">
  <h1>Array 1</h1>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in array1">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.value1[item.value]" value="{{item.value}}" />
      {{item.text}}
    </li>
  </ul>

  <h1>Array 2</h1>
  <script>
    array2 = [{
    text: 'Option 1',
    value: 'opt1'
  }, {
    text: 'Option 2',
    value: 'opt2'
  }, {
    text: 'Option 3',
    value: 'opt3'
  }, {
    text: 'Option 4',
    value: 'opt4'
  }];
  </script>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in array2">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="formData.value1[item.value]" value="{{item.value}}" />
      {{item.text}}
    </li>
  </ul>

  <pre>Array1= {{array1}}</pre>
  <pre>Array2= {{array2}}</pre>
</div>
```

SCRIPT JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function AdminEventsCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.formData = {};

  $scope.array1 = [{
    text: 'Option 1',
    value: 'opt1'
  }, {
    text: 'Option 2',
    value: 'opt2'
  }, {
    text: 'Option 3',
    value: 'opt3'
  }, {
    text: 'Option 4',
    value: 'opt4'
  }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible because Angular would have no idea which scope to attach the array to.  Here is a simplified solution to your problem of your controller being messy:

Have two arrays, one for each property `text` and `value`.

```
function AdminEventsCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.formData = {};
  $scope.array1 = [];

  var t = ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3'];
  var v = ['opt1', 'opt2', 'opt3'];

  for(i=0;i<t.length;i++){
      $scope.array1.shift({text:t[i],value:v[i]});
  }

}
```

This may be a little more code, but it looks a lot less messy.  It also allows you to easily add in new values.

Comment: hmm, if its only one variable indeed it wouldnt looks too messy. but if I have several checkbox list to be populated. It will still look like a mess :(

Answer (score 0):

I end up making factory to hold all my arrays, then use that factory in my controller